# Image insertion problem into DB in laravel

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5.4

I am facing this error while uploading an image with a title and description text to DB in PHP Laravel. I am using the same code for other webpage there it is working properly but the same code is not working here.

[image]

Below is a function code inside my controller, where I am passing tile, description, img and input names from a form.

```
public function submitFanfic(Request $request){
$user_id = session('userid');
$name = $_FILES['img']['name'];
$tem_name = $_FILES['img']['tmp_name'];
$dir = 'public/uploads/fanfic/';
$dir1 = $dir.$name;
move_uploaded_file($tem_name, $dir1);

$data = array(
'fanfic_title' => $request['title'],
'fanfic_desc' => $request['description'],
'img' => $name,
'user_id' => $user_id
);
DB::table('fanfic')->insert($data);
Session::flash('message', 'Fanfic Submitted Successfully'); 
return redirect('/author/write_fanfic');
}
```

Comment: 1) did you set permissions for Storage folder?

Comment: 2) try to do: `if ($_FILES["file"]["error"] > 0) dd($_FILES["file"]["error"]);

Comment: hmm, I have noticed, that you are trying to upload in public folder.. you should upload to storage/app/public, if you want picture be public for all users. Also dont forget to do: `php artisan storage:link`

Comment: I have tried this way. Still, it is showing me the same error.

Comment: I tried again and again and finally, the below code worked for me.

"

  $imageName = $request->file('img');
  if($imageName!==null){
   // get the extension
   $extension = $imageName->getClientOriginalExtension();
   $extension;

   $imageName->move( public_path('uploads/fanfic'), $new_name);
  }"

Answer (score 0):

I tried again and again and this code (specifically for image insertion into DB) worked!!

public function submitFanfic(Request $request){
        $user_id = session('userid');

```
    $imageName = $request->file('img');
    if($imageName!==null){
        // get the extension
        $extension = $imageName->getClientOriginalExtension();
        // create a new file name
        $new_name = date( 'Y-m-d' ) . '-' . str_random( 10 ) . '.' . $extension;

        // move file to public/images/new and use $new_name
        $imageName->move( public_path('uploads/fanfic'), $new_name);
    }


    $fanfic_data = array(
        'fanfic_title' => $request['title'],
        'fanfic_desc' => $request['description'],
        'img' => $new_name,
        'user_id' => $user_id
    );
    DB::Table('fanfic')->insert($fanfic_data);
    Session::flash('message', 'Fanfic Submitted Successfully');
```